# Show difference between purchase price and actual price of stocks

Tags: interactive-brokers

I would like to show the difference between the purchase price and the actual price of stocks in the Portfolio in the Interactive Brokers Trade workstation (TWS). I could not find such a column in the columns selection.

Comment: Do you mean _your_ purchase price, meaning the difference between what you paid for the stock and what you could sell it for?  Is there not a profit/loss column or something similar?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I meant. Unfortunately I did not find a profit/loss column

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better addressed directly to product support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click on a column
2. "Insert column before..."
3. "Position and P&L"
4. "Unrealized P&L"

Comment: IBKR's calculation is fine if you only have a single position.  If you have multiple purchases (or shorts) at different prices and then you sell a portion of your holdings, it goes awry.  For that reason, I keep track of my trades in a spreadsheet.